# SAP Crystal Reports in toolbox does not exist VB.NET 2010

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

i have problem with my project, 
i using `Windows 7 enterprise 64 bit`, and `Visual Studio 2010 64 bit`, i was Install `SAP Crystal Reports Run time 64 bit` in my notebook, but when i was open my `Visual Studio 2010`, in toolbox does not exist `SAP Crystal Reports's tool`,

anybody know where my error ? i have somebody can help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please note: To integrate "SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio" into VS 2010 or 2012, **you must run the Install Executable**. Running the MSI will not fully integrate Crystal Reports into VS. MSI files by definition are for runtime distribution only.

You should install CRforVS_13_0_X.exe which you can download [here](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824)

Hope this help.